# array and path curve

Tags: modifiers, path

here is a small question - I created a chain for a motorcycle using an array and a curve, I applied an array, and I don’t understand what to do with a curve when I move it, delete it, or apply into mesh, than copies of objects is disappear 
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please reformulate because it's not very clear, if you applied the array, then the copies of the object can't disappear...

Comment: I added a video, no array

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/